# Expressjs 4 route separation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm messing around with socketIO and currently I have a separate route file:

```
//api.js
var express  = require('express');
var router   = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  io.sockets.emit("change", {message: "this is a test"}); //io is NOT referenced!!!
  response.send(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

where `io` is referenced in my `server.js` like so

```
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8080),
io = io.listen(server);
```

Before using socketIO I included the api routes file and prefixed all routes with `/api` like this:

```
var api = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/api', api);
```

**Question:** How can I pass the reference to socketIO `io` to the routes file?

Comment: There are any number of ways, including exporting an init function that takes the parameter, exporting *just* a function that takes the parameter, etc.

Comment: Would really appreciate an example if you get time Dave. I thought about exporting the function but then I didn't know how I could still apply the `/api` prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api` prefix isn't related.

(Very) Roughly it would look something like this:

**api.js**

```
var router  = require('express').Router();

module.exports = function(io) {
  router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit("change", {message: "this is a test"});
    response.send(200);
  });

  return router;
};
```

**server.js fragment**

```
var api = require('./server/routes/api')(io);
app.use('/api', api);
```

You don't need to expose only that function at the module level, for example, you could expose an `init` function, like a normal module exposes functions:

**api.js**

```
exports.init = function (io) {
  router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit("change", {message: "this is a test"});
    response.send(200);
  });

  return router;
};
```

**server.js fragment**

```
var api = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/api', api.init(io));
```

I'm away from anything I can test with, but the nutshell explanation is that you want to expose a function that accepts the `io` variable. Inside that function `io` is whatever you've passed in.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. You could pass your instance directly to your routes like so:

```
// api.js
var express  = require('express');
var router   = express.Router();
var io;

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  io.sockets.emit("change", {message: "this is a test"});
  response.send(200);
});

module.exports = function(sio) {
  io = sio;
  return router;
};


// server.js
var api = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/api', api(io));
```

Or you could put your socket.io instance in a separate file that you `require()` in any files that need the socket.io instance.